# JS change content by click

Tags: javascript

I need your precious help!!!

I have 2 slides on the top of the screen and they change after 10 seconds(loop). You can see here: http://packageonly.tk/test

If you click on FULL info - on both slides - you will see the contents on the bottom of the screen - i want them to be replaced. so only 1 info is being shown at the bottom - ORR - I wonder how can i connect the content at the bottom to the top - so the content would change accordingly.

thanks

I have use this code so far:

```js
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("id1");
  if (x.style.display === "none") {
    x.style.display = "block";
    
  } else {
    x.style.display = "none";
  }
}

function myFunction2() {
  var x2 = document.getElementById("id2");
  if (x2.style.display === "none") {
    x2.style.display = "block";
    
  } else {
    x2.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="id1">This is id1</div>
<div id="id2">This is id2</div>

<button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">myFunction()</button>
<button type="button" onclick="myFunction2()">myFunction2()</button>
```

Comment: I think it's unclear what you're trying to do.  Do you want the videos to disappear when the "content" div appears? Is there something in particular that you want to display in the content div?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you're not making the old info disappear. Try this:

```
function myFunction() {
  var x1 = document.getElementById("id1"); // renamed this
  var x2 = document.getElementById("id2"); // added this
  if (x1.style.display === "none") {
    x1.style.display = "block";
    x2.style.display = "none"; // added this to remove the old info
  } else {
    x1.style.display = "none";
  }
}

function myFunction2() {
  var x1 = document.getElementById("id1");
  var x2 = document.getElementById("id2");
  if (x2.style.display === "none") {
    x2.style.display = "block";
    x1.style.display = "none";
  } else {
    x2.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```